# Why all those unicode commands works CORRECT in Python? They all print my character correctly, no matter what i do

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Probably I completely don't understand it, so can you take a look at code examples and tell my what should I do, to be sure it will work?

I tried it in Eclipse with Pydev. I use python 2.6.6 (becuase of some library that not support python 2.7).

First, without using codecs module

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

file1 = open("samoloty1.txt", "w")
file2 = open("samoloty2.txt", "w")
file3 = open("samoloty3.txt", "w")
file4 = open("samoloty4.txt", "w")
file5 = open("samoloty5.txt", "w")
file6 = open("samoloty6.txt", "w")

# I know that this is weird, but it shows that whatever i do, it not ruin anything...
print u"ą✈✈"
file1.write(u"ą✈✈")
print "ą✈✈"
file2.write("ą✈✈")

print "ą✈✈".decode("utf-8")
file3.write("ą✈✈".decode("utf-8"))
print "ą✈✈".encode("utf-8")
file4.write("ą✈✈".encode("utf-8"))

print u"ą✈✈".decode("utf-8")
file5.write(u"ą✈✈".decode("utf-8"))
print u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8")
file6.write(u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8"))

file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
file4.close()
file5.close()
file6.close()

file1 = open("samoloty1.txt", "r")
file2 = open("samoloty2.txt", "r")
file3 = open("samoloty3.txt", "r")
file4 = open("samoloty4.txt", "r")
file5 = open("samoloty5.txt", "r")
file6 = open("samoloty6.txt", "r")

print file1.read()
print file2.read()
print file3.read()
print file4.read()
print file5.read()
print file6.read()
```

Every each of those prints works correctly and I don't get any funny characters.

Also i tried this: i delete all files made in the previous test and change only those lines:

```
file1 = open("samoloty1.txt", "w")
```

to those:

```
file1 = codecs.open("samoloty1.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')
```

and again everything works...

Can anyone make some examples what works, and what not?

**Should this be separate question?**
I am downloading web pages, through this:

```
content = urllib.urlopen(some_url).read()
ucontent = unicode(content, encoding) # i get encoding from headers
```

Is this correct and enough? What should I do next with it to store it in utf-8 file? (I ask it because whatever I did before, it just works...)

** **UPDATE** **

Probably everything works ok because PyDev (or just Eclipse) has terminal encoded in UTF-8. So for tests i used cmd from Windows 7 and i get some errors. Now everything was crashing as expected. :D Here i am showing what i changed to get it working again (and all of those changes are reasonable for me and they agree with what i learn in answers and in docs in Python documentations).

```
print u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8") # added encode
file1.write(u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8")) # added encode
print "ą✈✈"
file2.write("ą✈✈")

print "ą✈✈" # removed .decode("utf-8")
file3.write("ą✈✈") # removed .decode("utf-8"))
print "ą✈✈" # removed .encode("utf-8")
file4.write("ą✈✈") # removed .encode("utf-8"))

print u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8") # changed from .decode("utf-8")
file5.write(u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8")) # changed from .decode("utf-8")
print u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8")
file6.write(u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8"))
```

And like someone said, when i use codecs, i not need to use encode() everytime before writing to file. :)
Question is, which answer should be marked as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just lucky that the encoding of your console is `utf-8` by default.

If you pass a `unicode` object to the `write` method method of a file object (`sys.stdout`) the object is implicitly decoded with its `encoding` attribute.

Thouse who work in Windows are not so lucky: [How to workaround Python "WindowsError messages are not properly encoded" problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668319/how-to-workaround-python-windowserror-messages-are-not-properly-encoded-proble)

Comment: Just commenting a bit: the PyDev console is utf-8 (which is the Java default) if you run things in the command line, you may end up having different results.

Answer (score 1):

All those write exercises in the code snippet actually boil down to two situations:

- when you write string to the file
- when you try to write unicode string to the file

Lets call string as s and unicode string as u.

Then fileN.write(s) makes sense, and fileN.write(u) doesn't. I don't know about your setup (maybe you have made some changes to site's python), but the following expectedly breaks here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                                                                                                                               
ff = open("ff.txt", "w")
ff.write(u"ą✈✈")
ff.close()
```

with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 5, in <module>
    ff.write(u"ą✈✈")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It means, that unicode string should be changed to string before writing to file. And your file6 example shows how to do it:

```
u"ą✈✈".encode("utf-8")
```

The magic string  `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is the one which enables you to write unicode string literals in a WYSIWYG way: `u"ą✈✈"`, it doesn't help you to determine your encoding in any other situation.

Thus, do not give .write() method in Python2.6 any unicode string. The good practice is to work with unicode strings in your code but convert from/to concrete encoding at the input/output borders.

The codecs example is good, as well as urllib.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct. See [this Python unicode howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) for more info.

The general principles are:

1. When binary data comes in to your application (e.g., `open()`, `urllib.urlopen()`), use the `decode()` method to get a unicode string.

   - If the byte string is invalid for the supplied encoding, you may get `UnicodeDecodeError`. In this case do one of the following:

     1. Use the second argument to `decode` to either replace or ignore bad characters
     2. try harder to find out what the real encoding is
     3. fix the input if it really is mangled.
   - For files, you can use the `codecs.open` wrappers to do this transparently for you.
   - Network data you must generally decode by hand, but sometimes the payload declares its own encoding (e.g., html, XML), and sometimes it doesn't match the header!
   - For database data, usually the database driver will have some method of doing encoding/decoding transparently for you and always give you unicode strings. Otherwise you will need to encode/decode by hand.
2. Use unicode strings in your application.
3. Right before the binary data leaves your application, use `encode()` on the string to encode to your desired encoding.

   - If your target encoding cannot represent some of your unicode characters, you may get `UnicodeEncodeError`. In this case do one of the following:

     1. Use the second argument to `encode()` to ignore or replace characters that can't be represented in the target encoding;
     2. Don't generate these characters in your application.
     3. Find an alternate way of representing them. E.g., in XML, you can use a numeric character entity.
   - For files, you may use the `codecs.open` wrapper to do encoding for you transparently.
   - For database connections, the driver will often have an option to accept unicode strings and encode for you.
   - For network connections, you must generally encode by hand. Sometimes the payload will be generated by a library that will encode properly for you (e.g., writing XML).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are correctly using the magic "coding comment," everything works as supposed.

Comment: Sorry, this is not completely right: "coding" comment affects mostly unicode literals (Python interpreter knows how to correctly convert them to unicode).