# print Russian text from file in windows using python

Tags: python, string, character-encoding

I have file each line 1 word,notepad++ shows ANSI encoding.

file looks like like(russian text):

```
вымышлять

тем|тема|то|тот

не

мало|менее|меней
```

output something like:

```
ЇхфюЁ|ЇхфюЁр
ьшїрщыютшў
фюёЄюхтёъшщ
чряшёър
шч
яюфяюы№х
яєсышўэ√щ
¤ыхъЄЁюээ√щ
сшсышюЄхър
```

my code:

```
import sys
print sys.stdout.encoding  #prints cp866

ins = open( "out.txt", "r" )
words = []
s=0
for line in ins:
    if (s<10):
        print line 
            s=s+1
    words.append( line )
ins.close()
```

but it prints wrong words.

Comment: Could you please add an example of what the file looks like and what the output is? Also, it looks like you're not increasing the s variable.

Comment: What is "wrong words"?  Example please.

Comment: add example.  "wrong words" means wrong encoding

Comment: Find out the encoding of the file (which might be different than the encoding of `sys.stdout`) and then use `codecs.open` to open it with the correct encoding instead of `open`.

Comment: Hi, It will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668319/how-to-workaround-python-windowserror-messages-are-not-properly-encoded-proble

Comment: try `print line.decode('ISO 8859-5')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming Windows.

`ANSI` on Russian Windows is `Windows-1251`, but the `cmd.exe` console window seems to use `cp866`.  Using the `codecs` module, the file can be read in and translated to Unicode using one encoding, and then printing uses the console's encoding:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('out.txt',encoding='cp1251') as ins:
    words = []
    s=0
    for line in ins:
        if (s<10):
            print line, 
            s=s+1
        words.append(line)
```

Input file (saved in Windows-1251 via Notepad++):

```
федор|федора
михайлович
достоевский
записка
из
подполье
публичный
электронный
библиотека
```

Here is the output to my console window configured for `cp866` via the `chcp 866` command since it is not my default:

```
федор|федора
михайлович
достоевский
записка
из
подполье
публичный
электронный
библиотека
```

Note, though, that the two encodings do not support the same characters.  The following characters are in Windows-1252, but not in cp866, and will cause Unicode encoding errors if printed to the console in cp866.

```
ЅІЃЂЌЏЉЈЋЊ—ґҐ–”“„’‘‚§…‡†•\xad€®©«µ¶±‰‹»›ѕ¦ѓђќџљјћњ™і¬
```

Answer (score -1):

The code has to be print(line)

not print line..

sounds silly but its how it works haha

Comment: Not if the OP is using Python 2.X.